# C# Encryption and Decrypt in React with CryptoJS

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, encryption, cryptojs

I have a use case where I need to send an encrypted string from the server side C# and have my client side that's using React decrypt the string with CryptoJS.

The issue I'm having right now is that the decrypted value is always empty, I also tried some other code and there are times where I'd get a malformed Utf-8 data console error.

C# code:

```
public static string EncryptString(string value) {
    var keyString = "E546C8DF278CD5931069B522E695D4F2";
    var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(keyString);
    var iv = new byte[16];
    byte[] result;
    var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();

    rng.GetBytes(iv);

    using (var aes = Aes.Create()) {
        using (var encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(key, iv)) {
           using (var msEncrypt = new MemoryStream()) {
               using (var csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
               using (var swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt)) {
                   swEncrypt.Write(value);
               } 
               result = msEncrypt.ToArray();
           } 
        }
    }

        rng.Dispose();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(result);
}
```

React side:

```
const decrypt = (data) => {
    // data is a string that's 'FtBMJGuLKqiISAIyN304PA=='
    const key = "E546C8DF278CD5931069B522E695D4F2";
    const decryptedContent = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(data, CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key),
        { mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB }
    );

    console.log(decryptedContent.toString(CryptoJS.end.Utf8)); // this always outputs an empty string
}
```

Any help would be appreciated as to what's wrong with my code or if I'm missing anything?

Thanks

Comment: In your C# code, you randomly generate the IV then throw it away. Your JS code has no access to that IV. If the requirement is that each encrypted string must be unique even if they come from identical plaintext, then you need to pass the IV too like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15440161/using-cryptojs-to-encrypt-in-javascript-and-decrypt-in-c-sharp and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073453/encrypt-cryptojs-decrypt-net, or write a logic that will generate identical IV depending on other metadata.

Comment: If you're fine with identical encrypted string from identical plaintext, and prefer the cryptojs simple single password solution, in .NET you need to split the key & iv from the password, like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76284645/cryptojs-aes-decrypt-in-c-sharp

Comment: Both codes use different modes of operation. The C# code applies CBC by default, the CryptoJS code uses ECB. For successful decryption the same mode must be applied (note: ECB is insecure).

Comment: Your key looks hex encoded and therefore should be hex decoded in both codes and not UTF8 encoded (note: *directly* using an Utf8 encoded hex encoded data as key reduces security).

Comment: Regarding the IV: A reliable handling is to concatenate the (randomly generated) IV and ciphertext on the encrypting side and separate both on the decrypting side based on the known length of the IV.

Comment: Thanks for the comment guys, I've got this working now with all your advice and suggestions. It was the IV not being passed, and key being the wrong format. I was able to resolve all this by appending the IV to the encoded string and separated both on the client side.